# Identify popup window Selenium in IE11 32 bit C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, popup, internet-explorer-11, ui-automation

I am having trouble identifying a popup to handle it. This is what I tried:

```
            string dialog4;
            string dialog5;
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                dialog4 = alert.Text;
                alert.Accept();
                dialog5 = "nothing alert";
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException f)
            {
                try
                {
                    dialog4 = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0).Title;// "dialog4";//
                    dialog5 = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1).Title;// "dialog5";// 
                }
                catch (NoSuchFrameException e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dialog4 = driver.SwitchTo().Window("iHTKK").Title;
                        dialog5 = "nothing window";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dialog4 = "nothing 4";
                        dialog5 = "nothing 5";
                    }
                }
            }
```

- The code wait 10 seconds and the webdrive wait 30 seconds after clicking the red-highlighted button to make sure that the pop-up has time to be caught.
- And the code return "nothing 4" and "nothing 5".
- xPath doesn't work very well in this project, I don't know why but I tried with different elements before but xPath do not work.
- **I could not open F12 unless I response to this pop-up. I could open it before and after the existence of this pop-up**.
- I also tried to find
  in the website (all HTML and .js files) for the information in the pop-up box using search function in Developer tool (F12) in Debugger and Dom Explorer tabs. 
  Nothing found. This is not my website.
- I attached the screen-shot with Window spy (an utility comes with AutoHotkey help identify windows). The pop-up was created by a process call "jp2lancher.exe". My Java version is 8.x 32 bit if that's of concern. While it seem like the pop-up is from a different process, I can't interact with IE until I response to that pop-up. However, I can close it via "Close all windows" action in the task bar and the pop-up will still exist.

What else can I do to identify this pop-up?[image: Pop-up screen shot]

Comment: What type of application is it? It doesn't look like a browser alert so `SwitchTo.Alert()` won't work. Did you check the element type of the popup in developer mode?

Comment: I could not open F12 while this pop-up exist. I could open before and after response to this pop-up. Not while it is there.

Comment: That's strange. IE might not allow F12 while an alert is present, try checking on Chrome or Firefox. If I remember, Firefox has a record and playback extension for browser events and it generates a script. That might give you some idea.

Comment: The IE driver can only handle alert-style dialogs (those created using the JavaScript `alert()`, `confirm()`, or `prompt()` functions) spawned and owned by the browser itself. As you note, this particular dialog does not appear to be one of those, as it’s created by another executable. How is this done? My first instinct is to suspect a browser plugin. At any rate, the IE driver will not be able to handle this pop up.

Comment: @JimEvans I really hope I don't have to use a new tool as that would create so much more work for many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing around, it's confirmed that Window Spy tool is a good way to identify if a pop-up is generated by the browser/driver. In `ahk_exe` line, it will say a window is run by which executable file. In my case, the pop-up is indeed a Java plug-in that is loaded from the website and run on my computer. I finally use AutoIt to handle that window. If anyone use AutoIt, keep in mind that it is a DIFFERENT language and all actions must be initiated in its format.